# Wordpress get attachment url using wpdb

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How can I modify this query to get the `attachment url` link to my custom post type.

I have tried several solution from the web but none of them are giving the expected result.

```
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT ID, post_title, {$wpdb->prefix}terms.name, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ', ') AS pictoInfos
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships
                ON ID = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms
                ON {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->prefix}terms.term_id
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
                ON ID = {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.post_id
                WHERE (post_type = 'recette' AND post_status = 'publish')
                AND (term_taxonomy_id = {$_GET['data']['id']} AND meta_key IN ( 'kilocalorie', 'difficulte', 'nombre_de_minutes' ) )
                GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC ",
        ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: Not related to your question: your code, as it is now, is open to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks. You'll want to use the [prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) method to sanitize your query before executing it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I only need to know how to get the attachment related to the custom post type. There is no user interaction with this code. Should I use prepare? I only need help on how to modify the query to get the related thumbnail to each custom post type.

Comment: You're injecting a string directly into your query with `$_GET['data']['id']` which is why I made the suggestion earlier. If you're 100% sure no one will use that to inject malicious code into your query then please disregard my suggestion. I, however, would still sanitize the query just to be safe.

Comment: You are right, I should sanitize to be safe. Any idea on how I can get the `post thumbnail url`. I can do it using `wp_query` but i do not want to get all the fields and do the looping pushing the data that I need into an array.